# Using polymorphic assignment

Tags: c++

I very new to C++ programming and trying to understand this polymorphic assignment thing.  I have researched online and have seen multiple examples but the only one that makes sense is tracking non-polymorphic memory footprint where you have parent classes and derived classes.  What if you have a parent class then multiple derived classes.  How do you call a method in the parent class using polymorphic assignments of variable of pointer type of a base class.  Thus, producing the output of the parent class and the derived classes using that method.  All I'm asking is for clarity as you should find in a book so I can understand this concept.  Then I will create my own test cases.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: there are a billion examples of this online.

Comment: Can you swing me one of the links cause I might be mis-understood.  It seems like I keep getting every example under the hood except the one I need.

Comment: You might want to consider avoiding such constructs.

Comment: I mean honestly, I would be happy if someone could post just one solid web link of the structure and concept.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to call functions/members of the parent class from pointers of the derived classes?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Could you make it clearer and write some code? Are you asking how to call both a derived override *and* a base default? Maybe like so: `struct Base { virtual void foo(); }; struct Derived : public Base { virtual void foo() { do_derived_stuff(); Base::foo(); } };`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:

    int baseVariable;
    base(int arg=0):baseVariable(arg) {}
    virtual void print()=0;
};

class derivedOne:public base
{
public:
    derivedOne(int arg=0):base(arg){}

     void print()
     {
         cout<<"Printing with derivedOne's print function.baseVarible = "<< base::baseVariable<<endl;
     }
};

class derivedTwo:public base
{
public:

    derivedTwo(int arg=0):base(arg){};
    void print()
    {
         cout<<"Printing with derivedTwo's print function.baseVarible = "<< base::baseVariable<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base *obj1=new derivedOne(5);
    base *obj2=new derivedTwo(7);

    obj1->print();
    obj2->print();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess that is what you are asking for.

Comment: I don't see any assignment here, much less polymorphic assignment.

Comment: Showing the output of a base class member function using polymorphic assignments of a variable of pointer type of base. Through this I want to show the output of the other derived classes by pointing that variable of pointer type to derived classes.  I hope makes sense.  Thanks for giving this example you did not have to mock that  but I appreciate it..   Example or website link is okay..   Thanks again.

Comment: I thought this was polymorphic assignment with base pointer...             base *obj1=new derivedOne(5);
base *obj2=new derivedTwo(7);

Comment: base *obj1=new derivedOne(5);
this line makes the assignment,am I wrong?

Comment: That is what I thought but then again I'm the one asking the question..  LoL..          I think we are pointing to the variable of the Base class"" base(int arg=0)""   and the assignment is being made this way..  right

Comment: Thanks  Osama Javed and guys I feel like I understand this concept now.  I appreciate your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old one, but perhaps another try at explaining Polymorphic Assignment (taken from Introduction to Design Patterns in CPP with Qt 2nd Edition by Alan Ezust, Paul Ezust)

Lets say you have an abstract base class:

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual double area() = 0;
    virtual QString getName() = 0;
    virtual QString getDimensions() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};
```

And you have two classes that inherits from this base class:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    Rectangle(double h, double w) : m_Height(h), m_Width(w) {}

    double area();
    QString getName();
    QString getDimensions();

protected:
    double m_Height, m_Width;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle(double r) : m_Radius(r) {}

    double area();
    QString getName();
    QString getDimensions();
private:
    double m_Radius;
};
```

And you have your main appilication:

```
#include "shapes.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

void showNameAndArea(Shape* pshp) {
    qDebug() << pshp->getName() << " " << pshp->getDimensions()
             << " area= " << pshp->area();
}

int main() {
    Rectangle rectangle(4.1, 5.2);
    Circle circle(6.1);

    showNameAndArea(&rectangle);
    showNameAndArea(&circle);

    return 0;
}
```

In the global function showNameAndArea, the base class pointer, pshp, is successively given the addresses of objects of the three subclasses. For each address assignment, pshp polymorphically invokes the correct getName and area functions of the Rectangle and Circle classes.